# Developing environment for creating a web application with a dynamic map

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frontend

my questions regards a "best" practice for setting up a developing environment for creating a asp.net core backend with separated frontend with a map rendering data from a database. I know this question sounds a bit silly but in the core i want to know whats a good way of starting this project when the requirement for this project is that the map can be updated via url. (Type of asp.net project, frontend libraries (leaflet?), ...) For example:
`https://www.example.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2` will render objects on the map depending on those parameters.

Best regards,
a user who has little to no expierence in web dev

Comment: It is quite a wide topic which may not fit for this site (Mainly for programming question). But for starter, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA5Fyt8sM7Y&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oVjOKgzsWqdFVvzGL2_d72v&index=3) is a short video by Microsoft showing you what is a Web API template, which can be used to update database. AFAIK it has a built in swagger as well, which is nice for testing and documenting.

Comment: I will have a look at it, thanks for now